# Sorting files in numerical order in Go

Tags: file, sorting, for-loop, go

I am reading a directory, and with this I've noticed that if I have files which are ordered by number (1, 2, 3, 4...) then it seems to use some alphabetic ordering.

Say that I have 13 files (named 1.md, 2.md, 3.md...), the ordering would look like: 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4...; The current code I am using to produce this order is:

```
files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(my_dir)
    for _, f := range files {
        fmt.Println(f.Name())
    }
```

The ordering I am looking for is 1, 2, 3, ... 9, 10, 11, 12, 13.

How can I get a strict numerical sorting on these files? Bear in mind that each file is named N.md where N is guaranteed to be an integer greater than or equal to 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you implement the [sort](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/) interface and order based on your requirements? Given the slice of returned os.FileInfo elements you can arrange them using an numerical order instead of lexicographical order.

```
type ByNumericalFilename []os.FileInfo

func (nf ByNumericalFilename) Len() int      { return len(nf) }
func (nf ByNumericalFilename) Swap(i, j int) { nf[i], nf[j] = nf[j], nf[i] }
func (nf ByNumericalFilename) Less(i, j int) bool {

    // Use path names
    pathA := nf[i].Name()
    pathB := nf[j].Name()

    // Grab integer value of each filename by parsing the string and slicing off
    // the extension
    a, err1 := strconv.ParseInt(pathA[0:strings.LastIndex(pathA, ".")], 10, 64)
    b, err2 := strconv.ParseInt(pathB[0:strings.LastIndex(pathB, ".")], 10, 64)

    // If any were not numbers sort lexographically
    if err1 != nil || err2 != nil {
        return pathA < pathB
    }

    // Which integer is smaller?
    return a < b
}

files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(".")

sort.Sort(ByNumericalFilename(files))

for _, f := range files {
    fmt.Println(f.Name())
}
```

I know its not very concise but is a valid answer.

Comment: I had this idea not long after I posted my question; I ended up writing it differently - but thanks very much for helping. I've accepted your answer because it would have given me what I wanted if I had used it.

Comment: @BenCampbell, You've added a syntax error with your last edit.

Comment: @DaveC Thanks! It's always risky writing code live.